# Android kitkat doesn't load webview properly

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to load a url via `webview`. Lolipop or above load it properly but in kitkat it isn't loading properly but partially .If I try to load that url in default web browser of `Kitkat` device it also failed to load but if I load that into chrome it load successfully .

Here is the code I used for webView.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

This is what I see in Kitkat

[image]

And this is the result of lolipop

[image]

Comment: Remove this line setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); and try to load it.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper tried but no luck

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the problem to load the page. Is it showing black screen or something like that.

Comment: Try this webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I tried setLayerType , no luck . I have edited the question. Added screenshot